# django cloud run custom domain redirecting to login

Tags: django, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

During development I an able to login and logout just fine. I have deployed the Django app to Google cloud run. I am also able to login with the `Service URL` which has the syntax `https://example-service-xxxxxxx-ey.a.run.app`.

Furthermore, I have also connected a custom domain via Firebase to the cloud run service and everything works well apart when I signin in which case I am redirected back to the login page.

Comment: Is the custom domain added to the [authorized domains](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/identity-platform#finishing-touches)

Comment: @GouravB I am not using any of the providers supported by Identity Platform for authentication

Answer (score 0):

So in my case it helped to add [SESSION_COOKIE_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name) following Django setting:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "__session"
```

[Firebase strips all cookies except from the one with this key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#using_cookies).